# Does EOF from fputc always mean ferror returns true?

Tags: c

A simple question, and I am about 99.99% sure of the answer but seeking some feedback so I can feel 100% confident in my understanding. When `fputc` returns `EOF` it is only on stream error correct? For example, say I have a very small space to write to, and the end of space is reached, `fputc` would return `EOF` as an error and not actually end-of-file? In other words, something like this is not required?

```
ch = fputc(c, stream);
if(ch == EOF) {
    if(ferror(stream)) {
        // error
    } else {
        // EOF
    }
}
```

Because if `fputc` returns `EOF` it is safe for me to assume that `ferror(stream)` will always return non-0?

I searched for answers on here, and I apologize if this is a duplicate question, but I am relatively new on here and haven't quite mastered the art of searching the knowledge base yet.

Comment: The [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fputc/) says *"If a writing error occurs, EOF is returned and the error indicator (ferror) is set."*

Comment: Aside: `ch` needs to be type `int` (or a wider signed integer type).

Comment: Thanks for the input guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [¶7.21.7.3 The `fputc` function ¶3](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.7.3p3), the C standard says:

> The `fputc` function returns the character written. If a write error occurs, the error indicator for the stream is set and `fputc` returns `EOF`.

So, for `fputc()`, your argument is correct according to the standard.  If there's no space left on the device or the output stream is closed (pipe or socket) or … then an output error has occurred, and `fputc()` will return `EOF` (eventually, when the stream flushes its buffer) and `ferror()` will report that the stream had an error.

The discussion would be different for `fgetc()` and input functions.
Then `ferror()` tests for an error on the file stream, but `feof()` tests for EOF.

You should be wary of using either `feof()` or `ferror()` with input functions — notably, see [`while (!feof(file))` is always wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong).

Your use is acceptable — you are checking after an output function (`fputc()`) returns EOF.  That would also be correct if an input function reports failure — then you can check with `feof()` or `ferror()`.

You can use `clearerr()` on a stream to clear the error and EOF indicators.

Answer (score 3):

In this case, reading the documentation should help. See e.g. https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fputc

> **Return value**
>
> On success, returns the written character.
>
> On failure, returns `EOF` and sets the error indicator (see `ferror()`) on stream.

There is nothing written about the literal meaning end-of-file, and this would not make sense for an output file.

Clarification: According to the ISO C standard, with `fputc` the return value `EOF` will indicate an error and not the literal meaning end-of-file. The standard doesn't specifically mention `feof()` here, so the return value of `feof()` may be undefined. To be safe you should check `ferror()` only.

Comment: Thanks, that's basically what I was wondering, even if a small space was filled it is considered an error, not end of file. So I am safe to assume that EOF returned would never result in `feof` returning true?

Comment: Just because `EOF` was *originally* meant to stand for "End of File," doesn't mean that's *all* it can be used for. Typically, it is set to a value of `-1` in a `#define` statement, somewhere in the standard hearders.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fputc) entry for `fputc()`:

> On failure, returns EOF and sets the error indicator (see ferror()) on
> stream.

This seems (to me, at least) to imply that a subsequent call to [`ferror()` on that stream](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/ferror) will, indeed, return a non-zero value (i.e. `true`).